# Change polygon color dynamically

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, qt5

I am trying to implement a functionality, where the color of drawn polygon can be dynamically changed. At the moment I have a simple test App where I am able to draw a triangle and rotate it. I then Added 2 buttons which are used to change the colors of all objects.

The rectangles and text colors change correctly but the drawn polygon do not. After random clicking the color change buttons eventually a new polygon is drawn but in an incorrect spot. I really can't tell what could be the problem.

Here is the code:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 800

    Ucolors
    {
        id: colDay

        canvas: "#eaedf1"
        text: "#0e0e12"
        spiderBckgrnd: "#f7fbff"
        spiderLines: "#C8CBD0"
    }

    Ucolors
    {
        id: colNight

        canvas: "#22212c"
        text: "#ffffff"
        spiderBckgrnd: "#0e0e12"
        spiderLines: "#3C3C3F"
    }

    property var colGlob: colDay

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectMain
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: colGlob.canvas

        Text
        {
            anchors.right: parent.right
            color: colGlob.text
            text: qsTr("text")
        }

        Button
        {
            id: btn1
            anchors.left: parent.left
            text: "button1"

            onClicked:
            {
                colGlob = colNight;
            }
        }

        Button
        {
            id: btn2
            anchors.left: btn1.right
            text: "button2"

            onClicked:
            {
                colGlob = colDay;
            }
        }

        Rectangle
        {
            id: rectTemp
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 374
            height: 432
            //color: "transparent"
            color: "red"

            Utriangle
            {
                trbase: 183
                rotAngle: 30
                fillColor: colGlob.spiderBckgrnd
                strokeColor: colGlob.spiderLines
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ucolors.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9

/**
 * @brief   Holds the color parameters of the whole UI
 *
 */
Item
{
    property var canvas
    property var text
    property var spiderBckgrnd
    property var spiderLines
}
```

Utriangle.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9

/**
 * @brief   This object draws an equilateral triangle in the middle of the
 *          parent object. The triangle at \p rotAngle 0 is being drawn
            starting from one of the corners facing down.

            \p hFactor of 1 will draw a triangle with the height that coresponds
            to the set \p base. Fractional values will make the triangle height
            shorter accordingly.
 *
 */
Canvas
{
    anchors.fill: parent

    // set properties with default values
    property real hFactor: 1    // height factor
    property int trbase: 50
    property color strokeColor: "black"
    property color fillColor: "yellow"
    property int lineWidth: 1
    property real alpha: 1
    property real rotAngle: 0

    onStrokeColorChanged: requestPaint();
    onFillColorChanged: requestPaint();
    onLineWidthChanged: requestPaint();

    onPaint:
    {
        var ctx = getContext("2d") // get context to draw with
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor
        ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.translate(parent.width / 2, parent.height / 2)
        ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotAngle)
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0)

        // drawing part, first calculate height using Pythagoras equation
        var trheight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(trbase, 2) - Math.pow(trbase / 2, 2))
        trheight = trheight * Math.abs(hFactor)
        var hfBase = trbase * Math.abs(hFactor)
        ctx.lineTo(hfBase / -2, trheight) // left arm
        ctx.lineTo(hfBase / 2, trheight) // right arm

        ctx.closePath(); // base drawn aoutomatically
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
```

The gui before changing the colors:

[image]

The gui after changing the colors:

[image]

After clicking the button for a while, eventually the triangle shows up in the wrong spot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color is changed but in a rotated triangle since the operations of rotation and translation are maintained, so after a certain amount of clicked you see half of a triangle of the right color. The solution is to save the state prior to the transformations and restore it after painting with save() and restore().

```
onPaint:
{
    var ctx = getContext("2d") // get context to draw with
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor
    ctx.globalAlpha = alpha

    ctx.save(); // <---

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.translate(parent.width / 2, parent.height / 2)
    ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * rotAngle)
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0)

    // drawing part, first calculate height using Pythagoras equation
    var trheight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(trbase, 2) - Math.pow(trbase / 2, 2))
    trheight = trheight * Math.abs(hFactor)
    var hfBase = trbase * Math.abs(hFactor)
    ctx.lineTo(hfBase / -2, trheight) // left arm
    ctx.lineTo(hfBase / 2, trheight) // right arm

    ctx.closePath(); // base drawn aoutomatically

    ctx.fill()
    ctx.stroke()

    ctx.restore(); // <---
}
```

[image]

[image]