# Change polygon size on window resize

Tags: qt, qml

In my QML application I am drawing a triangle manually using "Canvas" object. The problem is I cannot figure out how to change the drawn object size each time I resize the main window.

Preferably, it would be convenient If I could simply redraw the triangle each time a window resize occurs. But I don't know how could this be done in QML. In bare QT, I guess I would subscribe to window size changed signal. What is the proper way of doing this in QML?

Edit: The program is described here: [Change polygon color dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129901/change-polygon-color-dynamically/51130319#51130319)

In my main window there is a rectangle called `rectMain`. It is always the same size as the window. Then inside that rectangle there is another one, called `rectTemp`. In that rectangle I draw the canvas.

Edit 2: So far I have figure out how to react manually on window size changes:

```
property int lastWindowWidth: 0
property int lastWindowHeight: 0

function windowSizeChanged()
{
    if ((lastWindowWidth == width) && (lastWindowHeight == height))
        return;

    console.log("New height: ", height, " New width: ", width);

    lastWindowWidth = width
    lastWindowHeight = height
}

onHeightChanged: windowSizeChanged();
onWidthChanged: windowSizeChanged();
```

Comment: Could you explain yourself better, how is your canvas sized, compared to the window?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you want the red rectangle to change in size or just the internal triangle?

Comment: that rectangle has a fixed size.

Comment: Both. The red rectangle is just a helper container allowing me to maintain drawn triangles easier. It has a fixed size only for now. Now I need to change it to maintain the position and ratio between the main rectangle.

Comment: Sorry for this. In other words, Given the application view in the other question, I would for the ratio of the whole gui to remain the same (for positions and sizes). Although, I need to make some blocking function, that will not allow to flatten or widen the window to much in width or height axis. I need to figure out the behavior of each objects in case width and height is in different ratio than the given one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174142/discussion-between-bremen-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: In your code I do not see it necessary to scale the canvas, it is only necessary to scale the rectangle since the dimensions of the triangle depend on the rectangle:
`var trheight = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(trbase, 2) - Math.pow(trbase / 2, 2)) 
trheight = trheight * Math.abs(hFactor) 
var hfBase = trbase * Math.abs(hFactor) 
ctx.lineTo(hfBase / -2, trheight) // left arm 
ctx.lineTo(hfBase / 2, trheight) // right arm`

Comment: o change the size of the rectangle you just have to make a binding: `width:win.width*374.0/480`
            `height: win.height*432.0/800`